# Does "two-step" mean bureaucracy?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A conversation between a commando and a (retired) admiral from the movie [Sahara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahara_(2005_film)):

> Dirk: We could use some serious muscle here, admiral.
>
> Admiral: Well, you're not gonna get it. Not fast enough. I'm getting **the D.C. two-step** bigtime.

It seems that "D.C. two-step" here means *Washington-style bureaucracy*, but I can't find any dictionary to support it. All I have found is "two-step" is a dance.

Answer (score 1):

The "two-step" was a dance that moved back and forth but never moved the dancers any distance. For a while, it became a metaphor for any process that appeared to represent movement but was ineffective.

Comment: Can you supplement the answer with some real-life examples?